# How to pass extras to DeviceAdminReceiver?

Tags: android, device-admin

I use the following code to activate device administrator successfully.

```
public static void goToActivateDeviceAdmin(Context context, ComponentName admin)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, admin);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, Html.fromHtml(context.getString(R.string.admin_explain)));
    intent.putExtra("lock", true); // TODO cannot pass custom extras
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And code for DeviceAdminReceiver:

```
    public static class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra("lock", false)) // TODO cannot receive extra
            ((DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE)).lockNow();
    }
}
```

In the receiver, I expect to get true for lock extra, but it's always false. So how can I pass custom extras to DeviceAdminReceiver? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the receiver, I expect to get true for lock extra, but it's always false.

You are putting that extra on an `Intent` that starts an activity. That will not be transferred to arbitrary other `Intent` objects.

> So how can I pass custom extras to DeviceAdminReceiver?

You can't. You will need to solve your problem in some other way (e.g., `SharedPreferences`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE passing a PersistableBundle containing your value.

Then, you can take this value in the onProfileProvisioningComplete(context: Context, intent: Intent) of the subclass of the DeviceAdminReceiver

Comment: Here is the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE